# How to fix 'Uncaught TypeError: tagsInput is not a constructor' error while initiating custom JavaScript plugin two times on the same page

Tags: javascript, function, object

I've created a tags input Vanilla JS plugin. It's working fine when I initiate it for the first time. but when I re-initiate for another input tag. It throws this error: `Uncaught TypeError: tagsInput is not a constructor`.

[Working plugin code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/kvinbabbar/pen/BgRNab)

I've removed the extra code from the plugin for now.

**Plugin:**

```
    (function () {
                var tagsInput = function (opts) {
                    this.arr = [];
                    this.input = document.createElement("input");
                    this.wrapper = document.createElement("div");
                    this.options = Object.assign(tagsInput.defaults, opts);
                    this.originalInput = document.getElementById(opts.selector);
                    buildUI(this);
                    addEvents(this);
                }

                function buildUI(tags) {
                    //build UI code here
                }

                function addEvents(tags) {
                    // add events to tags here
                }

                tagsInput.prototype.addTag = function (str) {
                    // add tags code 
                }

                tagsInput.prototype.deleteTag = function (tag, i) {
                    // delete tags code
                }

                tagsInput.prototype.anyError = function (str) {
                    // find errors
                }

                tagsInput.prototype.addData = function (data) {
                    // add prefill data
                }

                tagsInput.defaults = {
                    selector: '',
                    duplicate: false,
                    max: null,
                    wrapperClass: 'tags-input-wrapper',
                    tagsClass: 'tag'
                }
                //make it global
                window.tagsInput = tagsInput;
            })();
```

When I initialize it two times on the same page it throws an error.

**Initializing the plugin:**

```
            var tagsInput = new tagsInput({
                selector: 'demoInput',
                duplicate: false,
                max: 4,
                wrapperClass: 'tags-input-wrapper',
                tagsClass: 'tag'
            });
            tagsInput.addData(["aloo", "bhindi", "tamater"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reassigning `tagsInput` to an element constructed by `tagsInput` - as such this will work exactly once, then because there is no longer any reference to the old `tagsInput` constructor, it will be garbage collected. Either change the name of the variable:

```
var demoInput = new tagsInput({...});
```

Or change `tagsInput` to be capitalized as is constructor naming convention:

```
var TagsInput = function(opts) {...}
```

Comment: Now, It's working. But I got another issue. When I initialized it two times: 

First time:
var tagsInputInit = new tagsInput({duplicate: false,max: 4,});

Second time:
var tagsInputInitAgain = new tagsInput({duplicate: true,max: 8});

Options of second time init are overwriting first time init's options.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `tagsInput` to a instance of `tagsInput`. Now when you reference it, It will be an instance of `tagsInput` not the constructor. You can fix it by changing `var tagsInput = new tagsInput({` to something like this: `var tagsInputOne = new tagsInput({` or `var demoInput = new tagsInput({`.

Hopefully, this helps.